# Ansible run concurrently a set of tasks using n servers

Tags: ansible

I m attempting to use together the strategy free and run_once = true so I can run concurrently several tasks on multiple hosts. Ansible shows a warning during execution it is not yet supported. Any suggestions on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the default strategy with async tasks?

Fire each task off and check for them later.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html#concurrent-tasks-poll-0

Comment: Sounds good thanks.  was hoping to avoid async so I do not have to keep track of tasks. Sounds like I need a seperate task to coordinate all jobs (wait for all to complete then decide on status etc.)